# Firebase Storage Rules

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I'm very new to Firebase so hopefully this is a simple fix ...

I have a couple basic storage rules setup just for testing, however it would seem that the rule for limiting the upload file size is not being honoured:

**Storage Rules**

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
       allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /photos/{image} {
       allow write: if request.resource.size < 3 * 1024 * 1024 && request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I have followed the rule code from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start

I have been able to upload a file over 5mb.  Firebase Storage reports file size of 5.33mb, more than the supposed 3mb limit.

To check that the rule is recognised (that I have the correct path structure) I changed it to only allow a file its name was over 3 characters - I tried to upload a file with a longer name and it didn't permit this as expected.

**Edit**

Current app side code to upload to Storage (very basic 'messy' setup!). Basically I have a image file picker that returns to `onActivityResult`:

```
    private static final String PHOTO_URLS = "photo_links";
    private static final String PHOTOS_DATA = "photos";

    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference photosDatabaseReference;
    private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> uploadSuccessListener;
    private OnFailureListener uploadFailureListener;

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        photosDatabaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child(PHOTO_URLS);
        firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference().child(PHOTOS_DATA);
        uploadSuccessListener = taskSnapshot -> photosDatabaseReference.push().setValue(new PhotoEntry(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString()));
        uploadFailureListener = Exception::printStackTrace;
    }

    @Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            switch(requestCode){
                case REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO:
                    uploadToFirebase(data.getData());
                    break;
                case REQUEST_CODE_AUTH:
                    // stuff to handle Auth ...
                default: break;
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            makeText(this, "Operation cancelled", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_AUTH) finish();
        }
    }

    private void uploadToFirebase(Uri imageUri) {
        StorageReference reference = storageReference.child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
        reference.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(uploadSuccessListener).addOnFailureListener(uploadFailureListener);
    }

    @Override protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uploadSuccessListener = null;
        uploadFailureListener = null;
    }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please post the code that uploads the file.

Comment: @qbix Hi I've added some relevant code that I'm using to perform the task - hopefully it will point where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results, but didn't copy all the details of your code.  Maybe add a log message in `uploadSuccessListener` that outputs `taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()` to confirm the size of the uploaded file.

Comment: @qbix Hi I think I have solved the problem ... From publishing new rules, to them actually being enforced for individual users seems not be instant i.e. If a 3mb rule is set it may allow uploads over 3mb for an amount of time or until user signs out and in? I ask because I was getting a 403 error (Storage permission denoed) on upload after I signed out and in again, meaning the rule was honoured correctly?

Comment: The [user guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#edit_rules) includes this: _Rules are immediately uploaded to Cloud Storage servers, but may take up to five minutes to become live_.  For my testing rule changes are visible within a few seconds.  Maybe location is a factor; I'm in California.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files#wildcard_matches), "If multiple rules match a file, the result is the `OR` of the result of all rules evaluations. That is, if any rule the file matches evalutes to `true`, the result is `true`."

Stated another way, your two rules are in conflict: one allows anything anywhere, so long as the request is authenticated; while another requires a file size limit. Unfortunately, due to the above, this means that files can be uploaded regardless of the restriction, since a rule is effectively "overriding" your deeper rule.

You likely want rules that instead look like:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /anotherPath/{allSubPaths=**} {
       // Only use named paths
       allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /{allOtherPaths}/{allSubPaths=**} {
       // Or explicitly call out the path you want to avoid in the condition
       allow write: if allOtherPaths!= "photos" && request.auth != null;
    }
    match /photos/{image} {
       allow write: if request.resource.size < 3 * 1024 * 1024 && request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP's rules only have one rule for `allow write`. I'm confused about what rules are being ORed.  Is there an implicit `allow write;` for `match /{allPaths=**}`?  I ask because in tests I ran, the OP's rules worked.  They rejected writes if file size exceeded the limit.

Comment: Wow, totally missed that detail... yeah, they are only `OR`ed if they are of the same type (all reads, writes, etc.). I'll try to reproduce.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post - as @qbix pointed out I don't have a conflict - I was doing this at the beginning, but soon realised the cascading rule conflict and changed to the code in the post, so I'm at a loss - I've updated to include the very basic code to upload the file.  The way I see it is that I have global read for authenticated users, but restricted writing on the `/photos/` path.